# How to integrate Selenium Testng (java) with Testrail testcases

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testrail

I have testrail project which is having test cases. I have Automated most of these test cases using selenium testng. I could not find proper Step by Step answer how to integrate testrail project - test cases with Selenium testng project. 
Where to find API and where to place that API. I would like to mark test cases on test rail as pass/fail once i execute the selenium project. Also how will this API create a Test run?

Answer (score 1):

go through the API documentation provided by testrail they have related repository on git too.
hope it help you!

https://github.com/gurock/testrail-api
http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/bindings-java